# undefined: $undefined showing in cshtml page after successful result returned

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple page that takes an ID to find a specific product from the List of Products returned from the database and then display this product in the html page.  I am able to see the JSON I expect to see when I use /api/products/12345 but when I try and query the data from the Index.cshtml page I get back the result --> undefined: $undefined in my page.  I will past the Product class and my html page.  Note, the display for ALL products renders perfectly.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public decimal MSRP { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Index.cshtml page

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>.:: Web API ::.</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Send an AJAX request - the second parameter is a callback function that is invoked when the request successfully completes.
        $.getJSON("api/products/",
        function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                // Format the text to display.
                var str = val.ProductDescription + ': $' + val.MSRP;

                // Add a list item for the product.
                $('<li/>', { html: str }).appendTo($('#products'));
            });
        });
    });

    function find() {
        var id = $('#prodId').val();
        // Again, we call the jQuery getJSON function to send the AJAX request, but this time we use the ID to construct the request URI.
        $.getJSON("api/products/" + id,
            function (data) {
                // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                    // Format the text to display.
                    var str = val.ProductDescription + ': $' + val.MSRP;
                    $('#products').html(str);
                });
            })
        .fail(
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#products').html('Error: ' + err);
            });
        }     
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>All Products</h1>
    <ul id='products' />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="prodId">ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="prodId" size="5"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
    <p id="product" />
</div>
```

The problem I am having is with the find() function rendering to the UI meaningful data, I am seeing that data matching the ID 12345 is returned successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: add a debugger before your each statement and check json object format

Comment: I'm guessing your web method returns a single object[not an array] when you specify an id, can you show you code

Comment: No, my web method has a GetAll which populates a List and when I try to get a specific product I can see that one product returned in my debugger.

Comment: public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            Product item = repository.Get(id);

            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            return item;
        }

Comment: You shouldn't post code in the comment section, its quite unreadable(just edit the question), also I'mm interested in the web method called for `/api/products/` not any helper method.

Comment: Musa it won't let me do that at this point.  The call for /api/products/ as I said before I don't think that will be all that useful but if you want to see it here you go....

Comment: I don't have enough space to add that call.  There is a List that is populated as a result of the call to get ALL products.  The call to get a specific product queries this list > private List<Product> products = new List<Product>(); and selects from it using Linq like this > public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            Product item = repository.Get(id);

            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            return item;
        }

Comment: Without code all we can do is guess, and I still think my original guess is correct

Comment: I gave you all the code you need.  The issue is not with the call which as I said populates a List of Products.  The GetProductById takes an int and queries this list.  I get the product back from that list without issue.  I can't show you that as it's in the debugger.  I looked through everything before I posted this.  The issue is with jQuery and how I am parsing through the results.  I need an answer as to why I am seeing undefined: $undefined.  As I said multiple times I am able to see an unordered list of ALL products without issue.  I see JSON results using /api/product/12345 no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to know for sure, but I'm guessing the code of the controller actions at `api/products` it returns an array of objects as JSON - probably something like this: `[{ID: 5, MSRP: 20.10},{ID: 6, MSRP: 10.10}]`.  Therefore using `$.each(data, function() {...})` to go through the list of items makes sense.

However, I'm guessing that `api/products/5` returns a *single* object as JSON - something like this: `{ID: 5, MSRP: 20.10}`.  Without the wrapping array, `$.each(data, function() {...})` won't do what you want.  Try this for your callback function within find():

```
function (data) {
    // On success, 'data' contains a *single* product.
   var str = data.ProductDescription + ': $' + data.MSRP;
   $('#products').html(str);
})
```

If that doesn't work, could you show a snippet of the data being returned by `api/products` vs. the data returned by `api/products/5`?

Comment: This worked like a charm Jonathan.  Thanks for taking the time to follow through what my issue was.  I knew it had something to do with the AJAX call in the .cshtml page.  Turns out I was the variable val instead of data to get my product description and price.